# Getting LNK2019 and LNK1120 even on a simple code

Tags: c++

I decided to learn C++ DirectX, but whenever I compile/debug a code, even the simplest ones, i get the LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@ 16 referenced in function "int __cdecl_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ) error and LNK1120.

I tested two different codes, one with class and other just int function alone:

```
#pragma once

class Main
{
public:
    Main();
    ~Main();
};

Main::Main(int x)
{

}

Main::~Main()
{

}

int example()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: its because you don't have a main function or the equivalent for windows

Comment: I did have main function before, but I still got the same error, so i tried example and yeah same result :T

Comment: Its Windows so you have to have a WinMain function somewhere that it can link with. If you are building a console only program then you can use the standard 'int main....', but if it's a Windows program you need a WinMain.

Comment: You should not modify your question to the answer when your question is answered.

Comment: Sorry I modified it because it might confuse the ones answering, and myself, i meant to put the main() :T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost you should do yourself a favour and learn C++ properly from a book. Bjarne Stroustrup, the designer and implementer of C++, has a great book which will teach you lots: [Programming: Principles and Practice using C++](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/)

Your program cannot link because there is no `main()` function, which is required.

[As Steephen has pointed out already in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32751935/4143855), you can change your program so it includes *at least* the following:

```
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

It looks like you were trying to substitute `main()` with `example()`, but your program and and C++ program needs to have a `main()`, as it's the main entry point of your program. You might also like to read http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/program_structure/

Comment: Still, you'll need a WinMain implementation. But yes, learn some C++ basics first.

Comment: The WinMain saved my life :D

Answer (score 0):

To keep you class definition intact do following changes

```
Main::Main() // you don't need a parameter for your constructor
{

}

int main() //Not int example() because you need a main for your program
{
    return 0;
}
```